# Cannot connect to a shared OneDrive (Personal) file through Power Query

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

I first upload an Excel file to Onedrive, then go Onedrive and share the file, getting a link with editing rights.

I then go to Power query  Data - New query - From other sources - From Web and paste the link there. But Power query seems to treat the data as a web page, not an Excel file.

I also tried everything suggested here: https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2014/8/17/using-power-query-to-get-data-from-an-excel-file-in-onedrive-via-url

Still I seem to get an internet page, not an Excel file.

Note the word "Document" in the left part, instead of "Sheet1":

[image]

The result in Power query:

[image]

When I try to expand the "Children" column, it produces more Name-Children-Text columns.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in the SQL Chick blog still work OK for me, editing the Excel Online link for download. Here's the link I used, which should work for anyone using Anonymous credentials:

https://onedrive.live.com/download?&resid=4FA287BBC10EC562!467

The change since the blog was written in 2014 is in the other credential options for private files - none of them work any more AFAIK.

Comment: Mike, indeed your file works, but mine doesn't. Here's the view link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsAdTBvimEwBgQDOyDID-yyf1Ljf    When viewed, the file has the following URL: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=14C98E21B4C1DC0!128&ithint=file%2cxlsx&app=Excel&authkey=!AM7IMgP7LJ_UuN8         So I use the following to connect to it through Power query: https://onedrive.live.com/download?&resid=14C98E21B4C1DC0!128   And it doesn't work! Note that your resid has 20 characters, but mine has only 19. Why? Can it be the reason?

Comment: I'm getting the same result as you with your link. I don't know why.